# Ajax works only once when using load event

Tags: ajax

I submit a form using ajax method and it works only once, then second time, the page gets refreshed without doing anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
function formSubmitHandler(options) {
    return function (e) {
        var $form = $(this),
            $submit = $(options.submit),
            $alert = $(options.alert);
        var $loadagain = $('#divtoload').load('mypage.php #divtoload');
        e.preventDefault();

        $alert.fadeOut();
        $submit.html('Saving Changes...').prop({disabled: true});

        $.post(options.url, $form.serialize())
        .done(function (data) {
            $alert.html(data).fadeIn();
            $alert.html($loadagain).fadeIn();
            $form.trigger('reset');
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $alert.html(textStatus).fadeIn();
            console.log(arguments);
        })
        .always(function () {
            $submit.html('Save Changes').prop({disabled: false});
        });
    };
}

$('#main_form_new').submit(formSubmitHandler({
    url: 'ajax/category.php',
    submit: '.sbbtn',
    alert: '.form_result'
}));

$('#item_main_itemform_new').submit(formSubmitHandler({
    url: 'ajax/items.php',
    submit: '.itemsbbtn',
    alert: '.item_itemform_result'
}));
});
```

I also have separate refresh button and without using that too (completely removed the following code), still it does not work, as I have tried multiple times with multiple variations, finally landed here for help.

This is the refresh code which am using with form credentials.

```
$('#maindiv').on('click', '#refreshdiv', function() {
//$('#refreshdiv').live(function(){
$('#divtoload').load('mypage.php #divtoload', function() {
});
});
```

html for refresh

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="refreshdiv" /> <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh </button>
```

How can I get it worked with both options?

Comment: Are elements #main_form_new and #item_main_itemform_new inside #divtoload or .item_itemform_result? If yes you should use delegation like: $(document).on("submit", "form#main_form_new", function(event){}); Every time when html is reloaded submit action is gone when you using $(element).submit(function() {}) binding .

Comment: yes, they are inside  #main_form_new and #item_main_itemform_new within the `#maindiv` and `divtoload`, what's your suggestion exactly?